# angular $compile link to controller does not load images

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to render a gallery in a bootstrap modal-box. I am compiling a template with an ng-init which contains the images. This works for the first page(it loads all the images and the caption). For the second page(in the plnkr click to the second page) it does not display the picture of the bear, but it does display the caption. I am already using the ng-src instead of src but this does not seem to work for images that are not loaded at the first page.

Plnkr test:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HuTimgo1GD21CEADh4kI?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using preloading images from this guy http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm